# \n and \t doesn't work in mdDiaglog - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text with break lines `\n` and tabulations `\t` in `mdDiaglog`. I've tried with Chrome and Firefox but I only have space where I put `\t` and `\n`

This is my code :

```
popup = $mdDialog.alert({
    title: 'Popup',
    textContent: 'Hello\nWorld\tHello' ,
    ok: 'Close'
});
```

Comment: did you try putting <br> in place of \n ?

Comment: yes and it's working with htmlContent but I would like to find a better solution (especially for \t)

Comment: why not wrap Hello in a label and add a left padding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good idea to use `htmlContent()`. But if you insist on using `\n` you can do that by some CSS code. You need to set `white-space: pre;` for `md-dialog-content-body p` class:

```
.md-dialog-content-body p{
    white-space: pre;
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-material-dialog-aqosgh?file=style.css) working sample.

And the result:

[image]